# Clicking on a link in Google Analytics shows me data for the link without the / at the end, which is incorrect

Tags: google-analytics, url, trailing-slash

Whenever I click on a link in G Analytics, it automatically redirects to show me the stats for the link without the obligatory `/` at the end.

Which means it shows me almost nothing, since I have WordPress and all my links have `/` at the end.

Has anyone else experienced this? Is there a way to solve the problem?

If I click back, it doesn't work because it redirects again to the silly reports.

If I click back more, I get an error.

Here's an example:

> An illegal state has occurred.
>
> The request resulted in an inappropriate state. Reload the page to see whether the problem persists.
>
> Error ID: c67296d9-bb43-4417-9230-2f07f25ca50f